# Getting "ambiguous reference" exception while reading nested json pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a below nested schema:

```
root
|-- fields: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- configdata: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- field: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- configdata:struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- field1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- type1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- value1: string (nullable = true)
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- score: double (nullable = true)
|-- siteId: string (nullable = true)
```

I have to read both the **configdata**: property from this json.
But when I am trying to do :

```
newDf= dataframe.select(sf.array(sf.expr("configdata"))
```

It is failing with the Exception:

> Ambiguous reference to fields StructField(configdata)

As you can see the configData is of struct Type and I have to read both the config data from this json.
Code developed in **Pyspark using spark dataFrame API.**
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 structs an no array situation evident. That is ambiguous as they are at the same level. Not possible. Give a new name to the second one: 'configdata1', at source.

Comment: Since I am new to pyspark,  could you please help me editing the same names at the same level while parsing in pyspark only

Comment: U need to edit the source or ask them to supply a different name for the second struct at source.