# Spark: Ambiguous reference to fields

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm getting the following error attempting to flatten a highly nested structure:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Ambiguous reference to fields StructField(error,StructType(StructField(array,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(double,DoubleType,true), StructField(int,IntegerType,true), StructField(string,StringType,true)),true),true), StructField(double,DoubleType,true), StructField(int,IntegerType,true), StructField(string,StringType,true), StructField(struct,StructType(StructField(message,StringType,true), StructField(kind,StringType,true), StructField(stack,StringType,true)),true)),true), StructField(Error,StructType(StructField(array,ArrayType(StringType,true),true), StructField(string,StringType,true)),true)

I can't seem to figure out what in particular is causing this. What is the ambiguity, other than a deeply nested Struct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462194/getting-ambiguous-reference-exception-while-reading-nested-json-pyspark

Take a look at the schema in the linked question. You probably have two fields on the same level with the same name.

Also, when you are facing an issue and writing to SO, please provide an example of schema and a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are doing a join between 2 dataframes, and both dataframes have a field with same name.
When you call for the duplicated field,  Spark doesn't know which column are you requesting.
Solution: rename the field in one the sides of the join, and it is done.
Example

- dfA is a dataframe with 2 columns => (id,name)
- dfB is a dataframe with 3 columns => (id,name,description)

You are joining both dataframes by column "id" and you want to select the "name" column in the second one:

```
val dfJoined = dfA.join(dfB,Seq("id"),"inner").select("name")
```

As column "name" is existing in both dataframes, Spark cannot identify which "name" are you asking for.

Solution:

```
val dfRenamedB = dfB.withColumnRenamed("name","b_name")
```

Now, when you are joining both dataframes, you would get columns "name" and "b_name", and you could identify which one is the selected one.

Comment: It is not strictly necessary to rename the field. One can also do:

`
df = df.join(df1, ['<same_colun_name>', 'inner'])
`

And that will keep only one column, and not the other

Comment: Not is the case. We are not talking about the field is used to join with, it is about fields are in both dataframes. In your example, "<same_column_name>" is the field to be use to join both dataframes, so the resulted dataframe only have this <same_column_name> once. But if you have same field in both dataframes, different to the joined one, in both dataframes, the error is raised, as Spark doesn't know with field are you requesting.